# How to get latest object in PageFactory without/with doing InitElements?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using PageFactory model in selenium framework (WebDriver, Java).

Test: Create an entity in application and wait until it will get complete ( To verify state of entity (completed/in-process) , I have to verify status image in-front of created entity).

Issues/Queries:
**** How should I wait for specific status should get change from In-process to Complete? (As whole page is not getting refresh after completion, only that image is getting refresh – AJAX/JSON Call)

***How should I get latest page objects using PageFactory? I have tried using PageFactory.InitElements(driver, classname.class), but it’s not working.

****Is any way, we can refresh only PageFactory Cache? Like SilkTest having ‘BrowserPage.FlushCache()’?

Answer (score 9):

The WebElements defined with the @FindBy annotation are effectively proxies.  Every time you perform an action with the WebElement it uses the locator in the @FindBy annotation to find that element on the page again.

PageFactory.InitElements(driver, classname.class) just sets up these proxies, it doesn't actually find the elements so you don't need to keep calling it again and again.

You can cache individual WebElements by using the @CacheLookup annotation, if you use this the WebElement will be lazily evaluated the first time that you utilise it, but from that point onwards it will not be looked up again (which means you could start getting StaleElementExceptions if the element changes).

The latest information is kept in the Selenium Wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Comment: If I have @CacheLookup annotation, and I know that at some point the element is already stale, can I intentionally void the cache and locate/lookup the fresh element again?